# How to determine OT Text Diff

Tags: string, reactjs, operational-transform, sharejs

I am trying to implement `sharedb` operations onto my front end code. I currently have it so that it submits an operation (https://github.com/ottypes/json0), specifically `text0`, when my `react` component triggers its `onChange` event. For example:

If my text were:
`Hello World`

and I delete `l` to make it
`Hello Word`

and then i add `s` at end to make it
`Hello Words`

I want it so that my OT text difference should have the operations to submit to rest of clients (unless this is wrong)

`[{p: 9, d: 'l'}, {p: 10, i: 's'}]`

What is the best way to generate these operations using a library or by hand? I looked into perhaps using `diff` library, but it does not give any indices of where the operation took place despite giving what the insertion and deletion operations are.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the browser-provided selection properties and onkeydown events to build the changesets by hand, or use a diffing library, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff_match_patch by Neil Fraser has been very useful to me (disclaimer: I am the publisher of that package.)